# Get user without email column

Tags: laravel

I have a database from which I fetch comments and data about the author.

I use axios to download asynchronous comments together with the author of the comment.

User.php

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

Comment.php

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

CommentController.php

```
public function fetch(Request $request)
{
    $comments = Comment::with('author')
        ->orderByDesc('id')
        ->get();
    return response($comments, 200);
}
```

I would like to fetch only comment.author.name and comment.author.avatar . Is there any other way than hiding fields? I think that I will need the other fields in other methods.

User.php

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'email', 'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify wich columns you have selected on eager loading like this :

```
Comment::with(['author'=>function($query){
    $query->select('name','avatar');
}])->get();
```

or simply :

```
Comment::with('author:name,avatar')->get()
```